# Bash: Logging stdout from multiple xargs parallel processes to separate log files

Tags: bash, stdout, xargs, tee

I am processing a text file with multiple parallel processes spawned by xargs.  I also need to capture the stdout from each process into a separate log file.  Below is an example where the output from each process is interleaved into a single file -- not what I want.

Ideally, each logfile should be numbered by the file line number, that is, logfile-1, logfile-2, etc.

```
cat inputfile.txt | xargs -n 1 -P 8 ./myScript.sh | tee logfile
```

It would be nice to avoid an external wrapper script if possible, but if there is a way to wrap myScript with a here document, that would work.

Comment: Inside myScript.sh do an `exec > logfile-$$` or some such?  Basically the script controls its logging rather than `xargs` attempting it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
nl inputfile.txt | xargs -n 2 -P 8 sh -c './myScript.sh "$1" > logfile-$0'
```

This assumes each argument in `inputfile.txt` is on its own line and contains no spaces. The `nl` command numbers each line, which pairs each argument with a unique number. The `xargs` commands takes two arguments at time, the first the line number, the second the corresponding line from `inputfile.txt`, and passes them to `sh`. The `sh` command uses the arguments to generate the output file name and the argument to `myScript.sh` respectively.

Comment: `"$1"`, rather than bare `$1`, but very much the right idea.

Comment: It probably doesn't make a difference since `xargs` splits arguments at spaces, but I suppose `inputfile.txt` might have quoted arguments.

Comment: @Ross, Clever solution.  I also want the output on screen in addition to the log files.  It seems to work with a small change:  nl inputfile.txt | xargs -n 2 -P 8 sh -c './myScript.sh "$1" | tee logfile-$0'

Answer (score 4):

You could use GNU Parallel instead and its `-k` option to keep the output in order, in a single log file:

```
cat input | parallel -k ./myScript.sh > file.log
```

You can add `-j 8` after `parallel` to keep 8 cores busy, but it will keep all cores busy by default anyway.

Comment: Have you looked at the source to GNU parallel? Makes rat nests look like models of good organization.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I have actually and I agree it is tough to read, but my experience is that it works a treat every time I use it. I also find it pretty hard reading the Linux kernel too... :-)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Improvements are always welcome, as long as it does not break current functionality.