# How to use xargs to output to different file names?

Tags: bash, xargs

Say I have a large amount of files in a list, like this

```
$ mkdir inputs
$ for i in $(seq 1 1 10000); do printf "$i\n" > inputs/$i; done
$ find inputs/ -type f -exec readlink -f {} \; > files.txt
```

and I want to pass them all through a script that looks like this

```
$ cat script.py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
args = sys.argv[1:]
output_file = args[0]
input_files = args[1:]
text = "got {} files".format(len(input_files))
print(text)
with open(output_file, "w") as fout:
    fout.write(text + '\n')
```

I cannot pass them all at once, because the command line invocation would be too large for the system to handle. However, `xargs` is able to take care of this for you;

> The command line for command is built up until it reaches a
> system-defined limit (unless the -n and -L options are used).  The
> specified  command  will  be invoked as many times as necessary to use
> up the list of input items.  In general, there will be many fewer
> invocations of command than there were items in the input.  This will
> normally have significant performance benefits.  Some commands can
> usefully be executed in parallel too; see the -P option.

You can see this in action like this;

```
$ cat files.txt | xargs ./script.py output.txt
got 2151 files
got 2152 files
got 2152 files
got 2152 files
got 1393 files
```

Here, `xargs` has broken up the command into 5 separate commands and ran each one.

However, the output file will have only the contents of the last invocation;

```
$ cat output.txt
got 1393 files
```

What I want instead, is to get output files that look like this;

```
output1.txt # got 2151 files
output2.txt # got 2152 files
output3.txt # got 2152 files
output4.txt # got 2152 files
output5.txt # got 1393 files
```

There is a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26167204/bash-logging-stdout-from-multiple-xargs-parallel-processes-to-separate-log-file) that suggests accomplishing this inside the script. However, my script `script.py` cannot do this itself, because it has no knowledge of the fact that it has been run `n` number of times on batched input sets. And in real life, `myscript.py` might actually be any arbitrary 3rd party program that I cannot modify to accomplish something like that.

So it would be easier if I could just use some kind of argument to `xargs` that would automatically fill in the number `n` of the batches that have been processed, such as

```
$ cat files.txt | xargs ./script.py output.{n}.txt
```

Does something like this exist? Is there some method to fill in the command arguments with the incremented number of batches that `xargs` has chunked the input into?

Comment: You could do something like `$ cat files.txt | xargs -IXYZ sh -c "./.script.py output.XYZ.txt"`. The `-IXYZ` option will cause the file names to be inserted into the `XYZ` string in the command. There may be a cleaner way to do it, but I have done something like this often. You can also use single quotes for the command. NOTE: this isn't exactly correct, as the list given to `xargs` is a file list, what yo would do is give a list of the unique part of the file names, then insert that. I think you get the idea.

Comment: yes I saw those suggestions but that does not work. I cannot use the `xargs` input line as part of the output file, because among other reasons `output./path/to/input/1.txt` is not a valid filename, and also I do not want a separate output file for each input file. I want to use the batches `xargs` already generates and reference that in the output filename.

Comment: Can't you circumvent that issue by outputting to stdout and redirecting stdout to a file? This is how I would do it. Another similar alternative is to append to output.txt instead of overwriting it, but outputting to stdout seems preferable to me.

Comment: I still need to have the name of a file to redirect to. I need to be able to generate the name of that output file based on the `n`'th iteration of `xargs`'s command invocations

Comment: @user5359531 If you are answering to me, then I don't see your point. `n` is dictated by your current system limitations which may vary from one system to another. If you absolutely need a filename, then give `/dev/stdout` and redirect the `xargs` command to your final file.

Comment: no, `n` here is the number of iterations `xargs` has done. I do not want the `xargs` output to go all to the same file, or to a separate file per input line. I want each iteration of `xargs` to go to a separate file. `cat files.txt | xargs ./script.py > output.txt`simply puts all the stdout from all `xargs` commands into the same file, which is not what I want.

Comment: @user5359531 Assuming that `script.py` is **not** in your control (it could be a binary executable), and that it is taking input filenames from stdin, you could do something like the following: `cat file-containing-numeric-values-1-5.txt | xargs -IXYZ sh -c "echo input.XYZ.txt | ./script.py output.XYZ.txt"`. The file `file-containing-numeric-values-1-5.txt` would contain the numbers 1 through 5 on separate lines. This is just an example, you can vary this of course.

Comment: `script.py` is not taking input filenames from stdin. They are being passed as positional arguments by `xargs`

Comment: it would be nice to be able to run them in parallel but that is not a requirement. I think this basic `xargs` method is not doing them in parallel.

Comment: Correct, you need to add `-P` (in GNU xargs) to enable parallel operation.

Comment: @steveb, `xargs -Isigil sh -c '...sigil...'` is a serious security risk; it's injecting your data directly into your code. Don't ever do that; just leave out the `-Ianything`, and write your code more like `xargs sh -c 'for arg; do ...; arg' _` so the copy of `sh` iterates over the items passed to it as `$1`, `$2`, etc. A line of input with `'$(rm -rf ~)'$(rm -rf ~)` will otherwise cause a very bad day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another method I have found that uses GNU parallel instead of xargs;

```
$ parallel -a files.txt --xargs ./script.py output.{#}.txt {}
got 1041 files
got 1041 files
got 1041 files
got 1041 files
got 1041 files
got 631 files
got 1041 files
got 1041 files
got 1041 files
got 1041 files

$ ls -1 output.*
output.10.txt
output.1.txt
output.2.txt
output.3.txt
output.4.txt
output.5.txt
output.6.txt
output.7.txt
output.8.txt
output.9.txt

$ cat output.*
got 631 files
got 1041 files
got 1041 files
got 1041 files
got 1041 files
got 1041 files
got 1041 files
got 1041 files
got 1041 files
got 1041 files
```

Answer (score 1):

**If, and only if,** you are the one that named the input files, and thus are certain they don't contain any fancy characters (i.e. anything that may break things or, worst, be exploited maliciously) then this may answer your question:

```
xargs -a files.txt echo ./script.py output.NNN.txt \
| awk 'gsub("NNN", ++n, $2)' \
| sh
```

Here `xargs` only generates the command line. Then `awk` subsitutes `NNN` with an actual number and the result is sent to `sh` which executes the line (that's the reason why the file names must be absolutely safe: into the wrong hands, this may wreak havoc)

Note: `awk` may also add a `&` at the end of the commands, so as to parallelize them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution I may have to use until I can come up with something better; pre-split the input file list and run `xargs`  separately on each split list.

```
$ split -b 130989 files.txt files_split

$ count=0

$ for i in files_split*; do 
cat $i | xargs ./script.py output.$count.txt ; 
(( count++ )); 
done

got 2151 files
got 2152 files
got 2152 files
got 2152 files
got 1396 files

$ ls output*
output.0.txt  output.1.txt  output.2.txt  output.3.txt  output.4.txt

$ cat output.*
got 2151 files
got 2152 files
got 2152 files
got 2152 files
got 1396 files
```

as for the number `130989`, I got that from `$ head -2151 files.txt | wc -c`, with `2151` being the number that `xargs` was originally splitting on in the first place.

EDIT: looks like you can actually get these numbers easier from `xargs --show-limits`

I am hopeful that someone else might have a more elegant solution.